# How to set $invalid true to a field in form through a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-validation

Can anyone please help me to set either $invalid to true or $valid to false through a directive.
When I tried to console.log(ctrl) I got an array named FD having names of the field as well as form name...
ctrl.$name gave me form name but ctrl.fieldname gave me undefined.
But the fieldname is present in ctrl. How can I move forward

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could solve this was by manually enabling or disabling ng-required.